# pull a tree with it's SHA

Tags: git, github, branch, commit

I'm struggling to learn Git, GitHub and got stuck here.
I want to pull a commit from this [Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpqQE.png) (It looks something like this Github), it's on upstream remote and it has a commit that I want to merge in my, origin branch. How to pull down a commit from a tree?

I had seen tags and branches but never trees. what are these trees?

Answer (score 0):

That's a revision ID (I would assume). That's what actually git works with. Branches and tags are just **pointers to revisions**. If you feel more comfortable working with a branch, then create a branch for that revision, play with it and then delete it

```
git branch temporary c3b039fb # create a branch on that revision
# play around with it doing what you want or need
git branch -D temporary # remote the branch when you are done
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: use the commit, not the tree.

A *tree* in Git is an intermediate data structure.  Unless you're doing low level Git programming (e.g., writing new Git commands), you normally don't need to even be aware that they exist.  But, for reference, each commit contains, or more correctly, *refers to* or *points to*, one tree object.  The tree object is how the commit retains a complete snapshot of all of your files.

Note that branch names like `master` are simply names for one specific commit, with the special feature that the one specific commit that `master` names will change over time.  Tag names like `v2.3` are *also* names for one specific commit, with the intent that the tag name will always name that one specific commit.

The level at which you will deal with Git is the *commit*, but usually by writing a branch or tag name.  That's for two reasons:

1. The actual hash IDs are big, ugly, and seemingly random.  They're no good to humans.
2. As we just noted, the hash ID for a *branch* name *changes* over time.  Specifically, the branch name identifies the *latest* commit.  So if you want the latest commit, you don't need to know its big ugly hash ID, you only need to know that everyone agrees that the name `master` holds that ID.  If you want the commit that's for version 2.3, you only need to remember the name `v2.3`.

Each branch name is local to one particular Git repository.  That is, *your* `master` is *yours;* it's not the same as anyone else's `master`.  So, when you have your Git repository call up some other Git repository, you'll find out what hash ID *their* `master` is, but that won't affect *yours*.  Let's say you assigned the name `susan` to this other Git repository: your Git will remember their `master` as your `susan/master`.

Hence, you'd run:

```
git fetch susan
```

to get everything from the Git you're calling "susan", then:

```
git merge susan/master
```

to merge with the commit that *their* Git is calling `master`, which your Git is calling `susan/master`.

(I recommend avoiding `git pull`, at least until you are quite familiar with Git.  Instead, run `git fetch` first, then poke around, then run your second Git command.  Note that `git pull` just runs `git fetch` and then *immediately* runs the second Git command, not giving you a chance to check out whether that's a good idea.)

Comment: Torek, I actually though of it being a tree id, not a revision id (as I implied on my response) but I assumed that that kind of information, tough available, would not be easily accessible to a end-user (adding a user interface that talked about 'trees' when they really meant 'revisions'... which people do every once in a while). @Bhavay, can you run this on the terminal and show us the output as an edit to your question so that we can be absolutely sure? `git cat-file -t c3b039fb`

Comment: @eftshift0: the image clip is tiny and may actually show a tree hash ID; I really can't tell.

Comment: That's why I'm asking @Bhavay to run the command so that we can be sure if it's a revision id or a tree id proper.